# Uploading Zip file on Google Drive in android

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a zip file on Google Drive.

The API I am using is:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files

The header I am sending is:

> uploadType: multipart/form-data
>
> Content-Type: application/zip
>
> Content-boundary: foo_bar_baz
>
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.Il-ByMiaTze0B3JTZKkzRLLIW0hTQfHorp7ISgiyM2xlsBqb0N_zie9Hr3CMMz56_8NoIHy_O4n3iwop5Sox3mN52LrSnRHaX-dwmB1uTm-wCHrNnsjsJeyKGn5bzpE0g

In body I am uploading the zip file in name parameter.

It was uploaded successfully and I got the following response:

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",    
"id": "1WFGJcDnC72PtXFpIAwz7zsRcQ8yLY9GA",        
"name": "Untitled",        
"mimeType": "application/zip”
}
```

Here I am facing 2 issues:

1. The name is showing Untitled.
2. When I am trying to download this zip file by using the following API:
   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1WFGJcDnC72PtXFpIAwz7zsRcQ8yLY9GA?alt=media

It is throwing me an error.

To hit this API I am sending the Authorization in header.

Uploading Zip file code:

```
void uploadMedia() {
    
    File file = zipFolder(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Xyz/"));
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> para=new HashMap<>();
    String strFile = "name" + Constant.HALF_IMAGE_PART_RETROFIT + file.getName();
    para.put(strFile, RestClients.MultiPartBody(file));

    Call<JsonObject> call= RestClients.getRestClientWithGoogleDrive().uploadImage("multipart HTTP/1.1", "Bearer "+token,"application/zip", "application/zip","foo_bar_baz",para);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            
            Toast.makeText(activity,"media_uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(activity,"media_fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Post Request:

```
@Multipart
@POST(UrlConstants.URL_UPLOAD)
Call<JsonObject> uploadImage (@Header("uploadType") String query ,
                              @Header("Authorization") String header,
                              @Header("X-Upload-Content-Type") String type,
                              @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                              @Header("Content-boundary") String boun,
                              @PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> para);
```

Kindly let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not just the headers you are sending we need to be able to test it.  Also in the future watch your formatting i had to remove a lot of invalid chars from your question.   The file is untitle becouse you are not sending the metadata for the flle including the title.

Comment: In which scope you are trying to upload file?

Comment: Please provide the entire code you're using to make the request or the complete request. I don't see you're setting the name parameter. Also, `It is throwing me an error`, what error?? Please provide the error message.